# Why we use reversed url identifier on Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, url, identifier, uti

Why do we use a reversed URL identifier like `com.yourcompany.noname` within Xcode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Same as in Java - to uniquely identify ourselves. The assumption is that if you have a URL, no-one else would use the same string.

Now why it's reversed, it's guesswork, but I'd say the question is wrong: it's the hostnames that originally got it "wrong" starting with the most specific thing, and it perpetuated down the history. URL of the form `http:com.yourcompany.noname/bigdir/littledir/file#fragment` would make much more sense(*), where you start with the most global thing, and end up with the tiniest detail, just like when reading time, or arabic numerals.

(Most date formats also did this wrong - the only logically consistent format is `YYYY/MM/DD`, if we use numbers like we do, with the smallest unit on the right).

*) Also, the creator of the URL, if I remember correctly, is on the record for saying that his biggest regret is the two slashes. EDIT: [found it](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/igeneration/double-slash-in-web-addresses-a-bit-of-a-mistake/3090)

Comment: @Erik: Conceptually, yes, although I've never heard endianness as referring to anything other than bytes.

Comment: Yeah - but it's all about where you put the most significant bit.  We are used to seeing one million written as 1,000,000 but there is no reason why it couldn't be 000,000,1.  Cheers!

Comment: @Erik: I did say, given the way our number system works, this is the only way that makes sense. If we wrote a million like `0000001`, `noname.yourcompany.com` (and `DD/MM/YYYY`) would be the sensible choice - but we don't. (Don't even get me started on `MM/DD/YYYY`.)

Comment: If we're going to talk endian, URLs are **mixed-endian**: protocol://3.2.1/4/5/6

Comment: @StevenFisher: Yeah, I was mostly talking about hostnames. URLs just plug them in unchanged. >.<

Comment: It's interesting to note that the Arabic numeral system was originally designed to put the smallest (least significant) digit first and the largest digit last. Europeans didn't change the order in which the decimal places come when taking the numeral system from right-to-left Arabic and using it in left-to-right European languages. So even the fact that the most significant digit comes "first" in left-to-right languages was more a happy accident than a design choice.

Answer (score 4):

Let's think about it philosophically for a moment.

Consider the case of normal URLs, e.g. `noname.yourcompany.com`. The highest level domain for this URL is `com`, since it's included in a gigantic set of other URLs besides the one you're given. For instance `apple.com` and `microsoft.com` both belong to the `com` top level domain. Then, `yourcompany` is the next highest level domain, since it belongs to your company and not Apple or Microsoft, but may itself include subdomains of its own.

In this respect, we can see that when we follow what we call 'normal URLs' from top to bottom, we are actually reading right to left. In programming languages, when we're doing scope resolution, we want to read left to right, because that's the direction in which most of us write code, and we usually start from broad categories and narrow down when we're trying to find that *one elusive function* we might be looking for.

That's why, in a namespace scheme that's designed to be resemble Internet domains, we end up with names that look backwards. In a certain sense, it's the Web addresses that are "wrong".